# How to clear kivy widgets?

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

I have an emotion recognition kivy app that can be done in 2 options, uploading photo and throughout camera video feed. I've use MDDropdownMenu to let user select.

The code for drop down part and upload photo & load video part:

(Edited: I add the part where I use the filechooser and also added my .kv file on the image part)

```
        self.menu_list = [
            {
                "viewclass":"OneLineListItem",
                "text":"Upload Photo",
                "on_release": lambda x = "Test": self.upload_picture(),
            },
            {
                "viewclass": "OneLineListItem",
                "text": "Open Camera",
                "on_release": lambda x="Test": self.load_video(),
            }
        ]
        self.menu = MDDropdownMenu(
            items = self.menu_list,
            width_mult = 3
        )
        self.menu.caller = self.wm.get_screen('main_screen').ids.capture_emotion_button
        self.menu.open()

def upload_picture(self):
        filechooser.open_file(on_selection=self.selected)
        self.photo = Image()
        loc = self.wm.get_screen('main_screen').ids.display_pic_emotion
        loc.clear_widgets()
        return self.photo

def selected(self, selection):
        if selection:
            self.choosen_image = selection[0]

def load_video(self, *args):
        self.image = Image()
        self.wm.get_screen('main_screen').ids.display_pic_emotion.add_widget(self.image)
        self.capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.detect_emotion, 1.0 / 30.0)
        return self.image


                    MDRoundFlatButton:
                            id: capture_emotion_button
                            text:"Capture Emotion"
                            pos_hint: {"center_x": .77, "center_y": .47}
                            line_color: 1, 1, 1, 1
                            on_press:
                                                             app.choice_dropdown()
                    MDBoxLayout:
                        orientation: 'vertical'
                        md_bg_color: app.theme_cls.bg_normal
                        radius: [40, 0, 0, 0]
                        MDBoxLayout:
                            padding: [10, 10, 10, 10]
                            adaptive_height: True
                            MDLabel:
                                halign: 'center'
                                text: "Camera Viewer"
                                font_size: 15
                                bold: True
                                pos_hint: {"center_7": .70}
                        MDBoxLayout:
                            id: display_pic_emotion
                            padding: [10, 10, 10, 10]
                            Image:
                                id: emoimage
```

But if you notice, both upload photo and load video utilities the same space. Which means when user click upload photo, photo will appear in that box. And when use click the drop down again but choose open camera instead, I want to clear the box so that video feed can be shown in the box now. But what I have now is, when I click the option in dropdown menu many times it will just add another box for photo/video feed. Is there a way to clear the space everytime the option in dropdown menu is clicked?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a call to `clear_widgets()`. Change:

```
def upload_picture(self):
    self.photo = Image()
    self.wm.get_screen('main_screen').ids.display_pic_emotion.add_widget(self.photo)
    return self.photo
```

To:

```
def upload_picture(self):
    self.photo = Image()
    loc = self.wm.get_screen('main_screen').ids.display_pic_emotion
    loc.clear_widgets()
    loc.add_widget(self.photo)
```

Ans similar with `load_video()`.

Comment: Tried this but then my photo won't be uploaded at all. I use filechooser to upload photo and put the loc.clear_widget under it. How do I fix this? Do I make separate function for clear widget and filechooser? If yes how to add the 2 function to md dropdown menu?

Comment: Edit your post to show your use of `FileChooser`.